# Updated Rails Error: SyntaxError in PostsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am new to ruby/rails.
I am trying to create a check box form that when the user submits what they have selected (it will send that value to a database (for a later comparison and return of a hash value).

**I UPDATED this post based off the feedback that I received below (thank you).**
**Now my code is doing the following (see below):**

I am getting the following error when I select:

SyntaxError in PostsController#new
/Users/user/rails_projects/SWORDMock_dev/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:15: unterminated regexp meets end of file /Users/user/rails_projects/SWORDMock_dev/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Rails.root: /Users/user/rails_projects/SWORDMock_dev

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None

here is my code from the posts_controller.rb file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:check_box, :label))
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end 

    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#show

    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:check_box, :label)
        end

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

end
```

Here is my new.html.erb file:

```
<h1>SWORD Mock Device Page</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <h2>Android Phones</h2>
        <%= f.check_box(:razr_max1) %>
        <%= f.label(:razr_max1, "Droid Razr Max #1") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.check_box(:galaxyS2) %>
        <%= f.label(:galaxyS2, "Samsung Galaxy S2") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <h2>Android Tablets</h2>
        <%= f.check_box(:asusprime3) %>
        <%= f.label(:asusprime3, "Asus Transormer Prime #3") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.check_box(:motoxoom1) %>
        <%= f.label(:motoxoom1, "Motorola Xoom #1") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%=f.submit "Select" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

I really need to understand what I have done wrong here.
Thanks!!!

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the new.html.erb file is missing the reference to "f." for the fields:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

Also as a side note the show method comes after the private keyword in your controller this should probably be moved up above private.

You could also explicitly create the form fields for the check boxes and use name = post[attribute_name_here] as an attribute in your check box fields, it looks to me like you will need some more explicit code to get this done since you are probably trying to save the selected item into one field for the post.

Comment: thanks for the information and help.  Can you explain your comment "use name=post[attribute_name_here]"? I am confused on this???